# MySQL: Select nth rows where at least have m attribute?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

so I have a database like this:

```
id            role              name
1             admin              A     
2             admin              B
3             admin              C
4             admin              D
5             user               E
6             user               F
7             user               G
```

Right now, for example, I want to query to get random 4 rows which have at least 2 admin role and at least 1 user role . Kinda like this:

**SELECT * FROM table WHERE role = "admin" AT LEAST 2 and role = "user" at least 1**

So what I want is like A,C,D,E or A,B,E,F but not A,B,C,D or A,E,F,G.

Is there a way to query like that ?
Thanks.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and this is a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the rows putting two rows for admin and one for user at the top:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by role order by rand()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by ((case when role = 'admin' then seqnum else 999 end) <= 2) desc,
         ((case when role = 'user' then seqnum else 999 end) <= 2) desc,
         rand()
limit 4
```

This assigns a sequential number to each `role`.  It then uses multiple keys in the `order by` to retrieve the numbers that you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=11dc65f523560d73b3af1d518c14da44) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL

like this

( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE role='admin' LIMIT 2 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE role='user' LIMIT 2 )